# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Code:public class PlaytechAutomationTest {

```
private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Setting system property for Chrome browser
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    // options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");

    // Creating a ChromeDriver instance
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@Test
public void testInternshipPosition() throws InterruptedException {
    // Navigating to Playtech website
    driver.get("https://www.playtech.ee");
```

Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null

```
at PlaytechAutomationTest.testInternshipPosition(PlaytechAutomationTest.java:30)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Show us your imports

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `driver` object 2 times. First one is at the class level `private WebDriver driver;` and second one is at method level inside `@Before` method `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`.

The `driver` which is being used in `@Test` method is using the class variable `driver`, which is not initiated and hence throwing NPE.

**Solution:** Just declare the variable once.
Change below line in `@Before`:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

To:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Still having the same error

Comment: @AnupamKrishna, Can you change this line `private WebDriver driver;` to `private static WebDriver driver;`. Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Now it is showing this-java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "PlaytechAutomationTest.driver" is null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "PlaytechAutomationTest.driver" is null

 at PlaytechAutomationTest.testInternshipPosition(PlaytechAutomationTest.java:30)                          Note: 30 line- driver.get("https://www.playtech.ee");